# STM32F1 write/read flash memory, cortex M3

Tags: c++, c, stm32, keil, stm32f1

I need to write/read flash memory in my blue pill board (stm32f103c8t6) and I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKgh896Bj8Q&t=32s but I used Keil uVision 5 IDE and I had this error

" #error 167: argument of type "uint32_t" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *" "

Here is the .c library I used

```
    static uint32_t GetPage(uint32_t Address)
{
  for (int indx=0; indx<128; indx++)
  {
      if((Address < (0x08000000 + (1024 *(indx+1))) ) && (Address >= (0x08000000 + 1024*indx)))
      {
          return (0x08000000 + 1024*indx);
      }
  }

  return -1;
}

uint32_t Flash_Write_Data (uint32_t StartPageAddress, uint32_t * DATA_32)
{

    static FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef EraseInitStruct;
    uint32_t PAGEError;
    int sofar=0;

    int numberofwords = (strlen(DATA_32)/4) + ((strlen(DATA_32) % 4) != 0);

      /* Unlock the Flash to enable the flash control register access *************/
       HAL_FLASH_Unlock();

       /* Erase the user Flash area*/

      uint32_t StartPage = GetPage(StartPageAddress);
      uint32_t EndPageAdress = StartPageAddress + numberofwords*4;
      uint32_t EndPage = GetPage(EndPageAdress);

       /* Fill EraseInit structure*/
       EraseInitStruct.TypeErase   = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
       EraseInitStruct.PageAddress = StartPage;
       EraseInitStruct.NbPages     = ((EndPage - StartPage)/FLASH_PAGE_SIZE) +1;

       if (HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&EraseInitStruct, &PAGEError) != HAL_OK)
       {
         /*Error occurred while page erase.*/
          return HAL_FLASH_GetError ();
       }

       /* Program the user Flash area word by word*/

       while (sofar<numberofwords)
       {
         if (HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, StartPageAddress, DATA_32[sofar]) == HAL_OK)
         {
             StartPageAddress += 4;  // use StartPageAddress += 2 for half word and 8 for double word
             sofar++;
         }
         else
         {
           /* Error occurred while writing data in Flash memory*/
             return HAL_FLASH_GetError ();
         }
       }

       /* Lock the Flash to disable the flash control register access (recommended
          to protect the FLASH memory against possible unwanted operation) *********/
       HAL_FLASH_Lock();

       return 0;
}


void Flash_Read_Data (uint32_t StartPageAddress, __IO uint32_t * DATA_32)
{
    while (1)
    {
        *DATA_32 = *(__IO uint32_t *)StartPageAddress;
        if (*DATA_32 == 0xffffffff)
        {
            *DATA_32 = '\0';
            break;
        }
        StartPageAddress += 4;
        DATA_32++;
    }
}

void Convert_To_Str (uint32_t *data, char *str)
{
    int numberofbytes = ((strlen(data)/4) + ((strlen(data) % 4) != 0)) *4;

    for (int i=0; i<numberofbytes; i++)
    {
        str[i] = data[i/4]>>(8*(i%4));
    }
}
```

And in the main.c I just used Flash_Write_Data(0x0801FC00,data);
It's all commands from the .c and .h files, and I also used CubeMX with Keil IDE (don't know if it makes any diference)

I don't know if it's a keils configuration problem, the .c and .h libraries used in the tutorial don't see to be so much complex. 
I searched on the internet and it's a very common error but didn't find a solution. I didn't even found much about Flash memory in cortex M3 with PAGE MEMORY TYPE. If someone could help with this error or write/read flash memory in cortex M3 I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please post an [mcve].  Trying to guess how you are writing, takes more psychic energy that I have at the moment.

Comment: BTW, you should be using `uint8_t *` when writing to the Flash, since a `char` type can be a *minimum* of 8 bits, *but can be bigger*.

Comment: In embedded systems, when writing an address to a 32-bit register, we usually have to cast the `const char *` into a 32-bit value, i.e. uint32_t.  Compilers will complain without the cast; their reasoning is that a pointer is a different type than an integer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow and also to embedded systems. I changed the post, hope you can better understand it. Besides, thank you for the tips, I will try type casting. I think I'm passing an unsigned variable to a function meant to receive a char function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: If `char` is bigger than 8 bits, there will not be any `uint8_t`.  The language forbids having any object smaller than `char` (bitfields can simulate smaller data types but they aren't distinct objects).

Comment: Also, one oughtn't to ever cast a pointer to `uint32_t`.  Instead use `uintptr_t`... the compiler will allow the resulting value to be sent to a function needing `uint32_t` on systems where this is safe, but catch the problem if you ever tried to port the code to a system with a different pointer size.